# Morph cube into sphere

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I created a cube of small sphere models that act as dots. The dots have coordinates:

{0 <= x <= 9, 0 <= y <= -9, 0 <= z <= -9}

The interior of the cube is empty so dots only exist on the surface of the cube. The empty spaces are represented as points at (100, 100, 100) and when I do the draw loop I ignore points which match them, which is why in the code I'll post below will have that as a condition for doing certain things or not doing them.

The goal is to take the points of the cube, and apply transformations to them to map them onto a sphere.

[image: This is the set of equations used to transform the points.]

This is the code to create the array for the cube positions then to create an array for the sphere positions:

```
// initialize cube array
points = new Matrix[10, 10, 10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            points[i, j, k] = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(100, 100, 100));
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        points[i, j, 0] = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(i, -j, 0));
        points[i, j, 9] = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(i, -j, -9));
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        points[0, j, k] = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, -j, -k));
        points[9, j, k] = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(9, -j, -k));
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        points[i, 0, k] = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(i, 0, -k));
        points[i, 9, k] = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(i, -9, -k));
    }
}
// end cube array initialization

// create sphere array
double d;
double theta;
double phi;
double r = 10;

spherePoints = new Matrix[10, 10, 10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            if (points[i, j, k] != Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(100, 100, 100)))
            {
                d = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(i, 2) + Math.Pow(-j, 2) + Math.Pow(-k, 2));
                theta = Math.Acos(-k / d);
                phi = Math.Atan2(-j, i);

                spherePoints[i, j, k] = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3((float)(r * Math.Sin(theta) * Math.Cos(phi)),
                                                                            (float)(r * Math.Sin(theta) * Math.Sin(phi)),
                                                                            (float)(r * Math.Cos(theta))));
            }
            else
                spherePoints[i, j, k] = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(100, 100, 100));
        }
    }
}
// end creation of sphere array
```

Cube:
[image]

Not a sphere...:
[image]

From what I can tell I followed the formula exactly, but it seems to only generate an eighth of a sphere. There also appears to be weird grouping along the edges.

Comment: @Leonardo I'm sorry, where does it say that in here? http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

The purpose of this site is to get help with programming problems. I'm not asking anyone to do my homework for me. I'm trying to figure out the cause of weird behavior in my code. Is asking for help against the rules of a site made to ask for help?

Comment: There's quite a bit on algorithms for generating the points for a spherical surface. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299981/generating-evenly-distributed-points-on-a-sphere http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16585/how-do-you-programmatically-generate-a-sphere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349727/generating-points-uniformly-on-a-sphere

Comment: @Pete Those all seem to be about making a sphere. The goal for this assignment is to morph the points of a cube into the positions on a sphere. The links seem to refer to making a sphere from scratch.

Comment: Then what is the question you are asking? I thought the question revolved around the fact that you're only generating 1/8th of a sphere. Perhaps you can make your question more obvious in the text.

Comment: @Pete Whoops, I just realized I didn't make it entirely clear, though the instructions in the first picture are. Regardless, I added the line, "The goal is to take the points of the cube, and apply transformations to them to map them onto a sphere." Though the of the post is directly about that.

Comment: I take it your working in radians?

Comment: Just a note - your problem doesn't specify that you have to use spherical projection, just that you _can_.  You could avoid this whole mess, statically generate your sphere and your cube, and come up with a random mapping from one to the other.  You can get a much cooler, wilder effect and still accomplish your assignment.  That said, it's important to know spherical mappings anyway - and that it should be done centered on the origin.

Comment: @Portaljacker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework if the tag has been made obsolete... well... it's kind of hint not to do something...

Comment: @Leonardo Maybe because there was a stigma attached to posts that got labeled as such? This is a place to get help. I was honest about the reason for it it and if you're not here to help then you're not contributing in a meaningful or purposeful way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're only drawing your cube in one "quadrant" (or perhaps "octrant" would be more appropriate), so you're only getting 1/8 of your sphere.

Instead of having your cube go from [0,9], [-9,0], [-9,0], focus it on the origin.

Once your cube goes from [-5,5], [-5, 5], [-5,5], your spherical calculation will be fine.

Just to give a bit more understanding of how this is the issue:

- How many quadrants will your answers be in when you evaluate Acos(z/d), given that d is always positive and z is always negative?
- How many quadrants will your answers be in when you evaluate Atan(y, x), given that y is always negative and x is always negative?

Out of the 8 possible quadrant combinations, you're only filling one.

Comment: So my cube now goes from [-5,5] on all axis' and I removed the negative signs from the conversion part. Though I still get a quadrant, though it looks more rounded. http://i.imgur.com/UmGfins.png http://pastebin.com/6iK2rmbs

Comment: Fixed it, my sphere part wasn't adapted to the new points the right way.

Comment: Good, because I wasn't finding anything wrong with your paste.  :-)  What do you mean by what you said, though?

Comment: Well i had fixed in cube making the points be at {i,j,k} - 5 for {i,j,k} between [0,11]. But I didn't do the {i,j,k} - 5 in the sphere part. Now I just need to do the animation part but that should be simple enough. I made a direction vector for each point from cube to sphere and will move them a % of that each frame until % = 100.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I didn't study it enough, and assumed you were using the points you made in the cube section rather than recreating all new ones.  Your way works, and may be better in the long run.  Sounds like you've got the right idea for the animation, too, so you should be in good shape.

Comment: I mean I'm not using them directly, but I'm using the same coordinates. I'm also checking in the cube array for points that should be empty. The animation looks super smooth btw, I move the points 2% of the way per frame.